# Taking fennel tea bags into Canada

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

My wife and are travelling to Canada from the UK over the New Year. I rely on fennel tea for my health, as it means I don't have to take a number of pills. It would make it a lot easier if we were able to take some of the tea bags we buy in the UK with us rather than having to go out of our way to buy some the minute we arrive.

Are we allowed to take [Twinings Fennel Tea Bags](https://www.twinings.co.uk/tea/fruit-herbal/pure-fennel-20-tea-bags) with us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this :

http://www.inspection.gc.ca/food/information-for-consumers/travellers/what-can-i-bring-into-canada-/eng/1389648337546/1389648516990

**Spices, tea, coffee, condiments**

entry permitted